# MALFORMED_SEARCH error with SOQL query in C# application

Tags: soql, c#

when I run this SOQL query via the Developer Console it works...

SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE Subject LIKE 'Order%Created'

or

SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE (Subject LIKE 'Order%Created')

But when I put this query into my C# application I get a "MALFORMED_SEARCH: No search term found. The search term must be enclosed in braces."

I've tried everything I can think of and reviewed all the available documentation that I could track down to no avail... What exactly is the SalesForce API expecting in this case??
remove signature

Comment: Have you had a look at the sample docs - might be a case of escaping a special char. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm

Comment: Can you post exactly what you have in the C# app?

Comment: my first idea would be to try replacing % by %25, but that could also be way off.

Comment: string soql = "SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE (Subject LIKE 'Order%Created')";

SalesForceWS.SearchResult results = Binding.search(soql);

Comment: @techtrekker - yes I have already seen that documentation and I have several other SOQL queries working just fine - it's only the LIKE operator that seems to be problematic.

Comment: @sdry - I'm using the API directly in my C# application via the WSDL/SOAP service - not the REST API.  I did try escaping the % just as a test, but the results were the same.

Comment: @MikeChale - code that's causing the exception posted above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted your code, but based on the error message it sounds like you're passing your SOQL query to the search function, when you should be passing it to the query function.

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly imported the Enterprise WSDL into VisualStudio and fired a SOQL Query on Contact with a LIKE, and it seemed to work okay. Here is the code below. I didn't need any special escaping for the %

```
String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact where LastName like 'Black%'";

  SforceService binding = new SforceService();
  LoginResult  lr = binding.login(username, password);
  binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;

  binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();

  binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;

 QueryResult qr = binding.query(soqlQuery);
```